# mysqli update works but insert doesn't

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

I have a simple table with 3 columns:

testID is an INT(11) auto-incrementing primary index

name is a VARCHAR text field

position is an INT(11) field

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require("mysqli.test.inc"); 

$name1="Rhonda Hotop"; $position1=456;
$name2="Perry Shafran"; $position2 = 789;
$sqlupdate = "UPDATE test SET name = ?, position =?"; 
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO test (name, position) VALUES (name = ?, position = ?)";
//create the connection to the database
$con = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }
//test an UPDATE
$statement = $con->prepare($sqlupdate);
$statement->bind_param("si", $name1, $position1);
$statement->execute();
$statement->close();
//test an INSERT
$statement = $con->prepare($sqlinsert);
$statement->bind_param('si', $name2, $position2);
$statement->execute();
$statement->close();
exit();
```

The connection works.

The UPDATE works.

However, the INSERT doesn't.  It does create a new record with the correct testID field, but the name2 and position2 fields are both set to 0.

Some help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO test (name, position) VALUES (name = ?, position = ?)";
```

to

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO test (name, position) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Tested and works.  I think I have looked at so many examples that my eyes just weren't seeing it.

Comment: @user2147001 You are more than welcome :) If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modify this line

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO test (name, position) VALUES (?, ?)";
```